# TCP client fails to read all data with read

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

I have TCP client and server running on the same machine. Both are running with synchronous blocking mode. The connection connect and accept works fine.

Server:

```
socket = std::make_unique<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(*io_service);
  acceptor_ = std::make_unique<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor>(
      *io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(),
                                                  port));
  boost::system::error_code error_code;
  acceptor_->accept(*socket, error_code);
  if (error_code) return error_code;

  // Initialize |buffer|.
  // write 1
  socket->write_some(
      boost::asio::buffer(buffer.data(), buffer.size()), error_code);
  if (error_code) {
    return error_code;
  }

  auto data = GetData();
  // Size of data is 722 bytes.
  // write 2
  socket->write_some(
      boost::asio::buffer(data.data(), data.size()),
      error_code);
```

client:

```
auto socket = std::make_unique<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(*io_service);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(
      boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(ip), port);
  boost::system::error_code error_code;
  socket->connect(endpoint, error_code);
  if (error_code) {
    return error_code;
  }

  // This data won't be read from server. 
  socket->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer.data(), buffer.size()),
                     error_code);

// Read from write 1
  boost::asio::streambuf buffer1;
  boost::asio::read(*socket, buffer, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(8),
                    error_code);
   buffer1.consume(8);
  // Read from write 2
  // Extract length from buffer1. |len_bytes|
 boost::asio::read(*socket,
                    buffer1,
                    boost::asio::transfer_at_least(len_bytes),
                    error_code);
```

Read for write 1 is working fine. However, write 2 writes 722 bytes and read 2 blocks if I specify 722 bytes in completion handler. 
If I call `socket->available(error_code)` before read 2, it gives 218.
If I duplicate write 2, I get 722 + 218 bytes. I tried putting `sleep()` as well.
 Whats going wrong here?

Comment: No hints in `error_code`?

Comment: @user4581301 Nope. Everything is success.

Comment: Can you implement the code using async read/write using boost?

Comment: Dunno if it's the case here, but often people new to TCP assume that because the sender sent N bytes in one call to `send()`, that means the receive will receive N bytes in one call to `recv()`; however that's not a valid assumption.  Since TCP is a streaming protocol, the 'chunk size' returned by `recv()` is not necessarily equal to the amount previously passed to `send()`, so e.g. if you sent 718 bytes, the receiver might read multiple smaller amounts of data (that will add up to 718 bytes eventually) but won't necessarily receive 718 bytes at once.

Comment: Nobody in TCP or ASIO -land knows there's any difference between write 1 and write 2. They'll almost certainly be mushed into the same packet. Read 1 will read at least 8 bytes but unless I'm misreading the docs, my ASIO-fu is weak,  will get up to the buffer's length.

Comment: What is your proof that the number of bytes written is what you think it is? Do you know what Boost's documentation says about the value returned from `write_some()`?

Comment: @user4581301 Ahh.. thanks for the catch. My read 1 somehow reads more data than completion condition and it is reading part of data from write 2.

Comment: The current completion condition is "at least", as in "No less than 8, but if there's more..., [FEED ME, SEYMOUR!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7SkrYF8lCU)".  `transfer_all` doesn't look like the right solution unless you make another buffer of size 8 and I'm not seeing a `transfer_exactly`.